# How to find the difference in meter between two geo points in maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

What would be the best way to know the nearest place of the list against the current user location.
is there a way to calculate the difference between two geo points in maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the distance between 2 points making 2 Location objects (one for each point) and calling the method `distanceTo`.

Example.

```
// Instantiate.
Location pointOne=new Location("");
Location pointTwo=new Location("");

// Configure.
pointOne.setLatitude(doubleValue);
pointOne.setLongitude(doubleValue);
pointTwo.setLatitude(doubleValue);
pointTwo.setLongitude(doubleValue);

// Calculate distance.
float distanceInMeters=pointOne.distanceTo(pointTwo);
```

And that's all.
By the way, watch your grammar for better readibility =)

Good luck.